# prepend and append a string to all elements of an array without using a temporary variable

Tags: bash

Is there a way to both prepend and append a string to all elements of an array without using a temporary variable, i.e. only using shell parameter expansion?

Having an array

```bash
a=(1 2 3)
```

we prepend a string to every element, e.g. "[" as follows

```bash
$ echo ${a[@]/#/[}
[1 [2 [3
```

and we apend a string to every element, e.g. "]" as follows

```bash
$ echo ${a[@]/%/]}
1] 2] 3]
```

I we want to both prepend "[" and append "]" (i.e. kind of enclose) we do something like the following (but we need a temp variable `tmp`):

```bash
$ a=(1 2 3)
tmp=(${a[@]/#/[})
echo ${tmp[@]/%/]}
[1] [2] [3]
```

Is there something like the following?

```
# the following is not working!!!
${             /%/]}
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  (${a[@]/#/[})
# embed the resulting array of the prepending parameter expansion
```

Answer (score 3):

If you've got Bash 5.2 (released in September 2022) you can do:

```
echo "${a[@]/*/[&]}"
```

This is due to the new `patsub_replacement` option, which is enabled by default.  See [The Shopt Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) section of the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use just parameter expansion to achieve that. But you can use e.g. `printf`:

```
a=(1 2 3)
printf '[%s] ' "${a[@]}"
echo
```

`printf` will output the formatted string for each element of the array.

Comment: thanks. I'd like to get the result assignable to a variable. Not just printed

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reassign to the array without a temporary variable in the middle you can combine `readarray` and `printf`, making sure to terminate strings with a null byte instead of a newline in case the data in `a` happens to contain newlines.

```
#!/bin/bash
a=(1 2 3)
readarray -d '' a < <( printf '[%s]\0' "${a[@]}" )
declare -p a
# prints declare -a a=([0]="[1]" [1]="[2]" [2]="[3]")
```